# How to hide multiple subfolder with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, web, hide, subdirectory

`http://www.example.com/blog/demo/first-post`

`http://www.example.com/blog/test/second-post`

I would like to rewrite the above url to

`http://www.example.com/first-post`

`http://www.example.com/second-post`

I used:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /demo/$1 [L]
```

But it doesn't work for ***test***. Please help.